# find the point at which two Paths cross in android

Tags: android, graphics, geometry, trigonometry

Okay, so I have two very simple separate Path objects, one containing a straight line I created with lineTo and one containing a curve that I generated with the quadTo function.  I need to get the POINT (x, y) where these two objects insect, which they only do once as well as the DISTANCE from one side of the arc of the point where they intersect.

There are lots of posts about figuring out IF they intersect, but I can't find any information on how to figure out WHERE they intersect.

EDIT!  I still can't figure this out, I've been trying to fake it by measuring the distance along the yellow line that the black lines were drawn apart from each other and then making a whole new curve.  It's sloppy and not working well.  [See the image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiDfX.png)

If I can get to the distance from the end where the black curve intersects the yellow line, I can get a segment of the curve, and the two points on it's end, and it will work great!

Any ideas, anyone?  :)

Thanks!

Comment: Having the distance of the beginning of the yellow line along the first curved path, there must be some formula that can describe the distance to where the yellow line crosses the second one, since they are uniform distance apart, or at least, I tried to make them such.

Comment: I was unable to find an answer to this question, I don't think it can be done.  My solution so far has been to take a different approach that doesn't require finding that out.

Comment: might i ask what the black paths are? maybe you can simply replace them with parabels or ellipses?